# Disable Angular routing, just for first request (when sending pre-rendered html)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, seo, pug

I'm trying to make my angular app/website as SEO-friendly as possible.

It's based on the angular-fullstack generator (Yeoman) and I'd like the initial request to serve completely pre-rendered HTML for two reasons.

1. Search engines will see the page as end-users would once rendered.
2. It saves making extra requests to the server('s API's) for data, which can just be sent in that initial request.

I've seen the services that can detect and send crawlers a different URL (which only renders static HTML), but was wondering if there was a simpler/more DRY way of doing what I want before going down that route.

If I serve the pre-rendered HTML with the rest of my angular code, it works fine, but the page is instantly reloaded as angular's router parses the route and loads it's templates. Some way to disable the angular router from initializing until a route is requested would work (rather than immediately parsing the URL on app initialization). Is that possible?

Comment: with http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouter you could intercept just for the $state.current.name if is index && !memory.get Memory.set do something btw have you got a server ? does your data look like ?

Comment: Hello, do you solve to your issue? Can you share it?